# Deleting the MySQL 'root' user on purpose triggers "Access denied" for other MySQL accounts

Tags: mysql

I have one MySQL 5.6 running in production with a legacy `root` account that is used for years. As part of a hardening program, I wanted to remove this `root` account - make it available via another account not named `root` basically.

After creating another account named `adminacc` with full accesses on the DB, I deleted the account named `root`.
Right after this action, all (`adminacc` could still log in) my others accounts could not log in anymore receiving the below message

```
SQL State 28000 Error 1045: Access denied for user 'XXX'@'wathever' (using password: YES)
```

I granted the denied account full accesses on the DB - without success.
I finally recreated my `root` account (with the same previous password, not sure if relevant here) and my DB accounts went back.

How can it be there is a dependency between an account (would it be the initial `root`) and another in MySQL? Would it be because I created this other account while connected as `root` user? Or the other account is trying to query a view created by the `root` account? I believe not, just throwing thoughts trying to understand.

What I found the most weird in my senario is that the connection from the denied account was not completely denied. When testing the connection from a Windows `odbcad32.exe` utility, it succeedded! But whenever used in app context (running from the same windows host), it failed.

I did run a capture and here is the output (this is from the app context)
[image]
You can see the login actually happens well; few queries are executed properly (basically init statments at session opening like `SET NAMES utf8` or `SET SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL = 0`).
Then the error is thrown when the user tries to execute a SELECT against one of the DB views.

Nota: I found no recommendation from MySQL docs to not delete the initial `root` account. Nothing describing such situation. Browsing a bit on the internet, I found [this previous StackOverflow question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46903/deleting-the-mysql-root-user-on-purpose) but it remained unanswered.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the result of `SELECT Host, User, plugin, authentication_string FROM mysql.user` to your question after you have deleted the `root` user. Then show exactly how you try to connect to the MySQL database with the other non-admin users, what the login credentials are and what the error messages are you get.

Comment: Stored objects (procedures, functions, triggers) have DEFINER property. When not specified explicitly the DEFINER is current user (creator, the account under which the object was created). Also the object have SQL SECURITY property, when not specified explicitly then DEFINER is used as an account whose privileges are used for object execution. You have dropped `root` which have been used as definer and whose access privileges were used while object execution, so current user (invoker) is now used instead. But current account have no needed privileges - and the execution fails.

Comment: Solution - try to re-create `root@localhost` with complete privileges pack. Should solve. If not then re-create all problematic stored objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by [Akina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10138734/akina), this issue was tied to [Stored Object Access Control](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-objects-security.html) in MySQL. Not only this applies to procedures, functions, triggers but views as well, read this

> For stored routines (procedures and functions) and views, the object
> definition can include an SQL SECURITY characteristic with a value of
> DEFINER or INVOKER to specify whether the object executes in definer
> or invoker context. If the definition omits the SQL SECURITY
> characteristic, the default is definer context.

My errors actually appear whenever a view was called (and because all of the views were created via this `root` account and with the `SQL SECURITY` set to `DEFINER` - default behavior).

Making a lot of sense now. That being said, the MySQL error message could have been more descriptive on the actual issue!